# Flutter countdown not counting down

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, timer, countdown

I'm kind of new to the flutter programming so I'm trying to create some basic things to learn. Currently, I'm trying to create a list of countdowns to a specific date. Nothing fancy, the dates are retrieved through firestore and then shown in a list. However, I encountered a small issue:

All the dates start at the same hour, for now, this is 00:00:00, which means they should have the same seconds in the countdown at all times. This ***was*** not the case. I posted this question earlier this week and the issue was that I always used a new value for DateTime.now() so I 'solved' that part by creating a new variable in the main widget and passing it to the countdown. I used milliseconds and microseconds in this example because everything loads faster. But as you can see, now the mill/micro/seconds are nicely aligned ([image from mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocfoq.jpg)), but it's not counting down anymore. So I'm reposting but now with a verifiable example in dartpad which can be found [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5561147bc269dcebb79005093943cb65). This code should be usable as well to replicate the problem on your local machine.

If I reload the app, it updates because the currentTime gets a new value of course.

Is anybody that could help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are passing the `currentTime` it stays the same. Because the `currentTime` is initialized only once.

```dart
  DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
```

And used

```dart
CountdownWidget(
    startDate: DateTime(2023, 1), currentTime: currentTime),
```

The `currentTime` value never get changes including the `CountdownWidget` widget. Therefore the UI doesnt update.

You can change the value of `CountdownWidget` from parent widget and pass the instance `CountdownWidget`, the current way.

**Solution 1:**
The solution will be

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      currentTime = DateTime.now();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

It is changing the `currentTime` on every second and passing the value, then updating the parent widget.

---

**Solution 0:**

Another solution will be handling the update on `CountdownWidget`

```dart
class CountdownWidgetState extends State<CountdownWidget> {
  Timer? timer;

  late DateTime currentTime = widget.currentTime;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(microseconds: 1), (timer) {
      currentTime = DateTime.now();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```